# React redux - componentDidMount fetching vs action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

If I use react with redux - does it always necessary to fetch data from the redux action? Or it depends if I need the data to be stateful?

For example: I have a container which displays a user profile page. Can I fetch its data from the componentDidMount?

Thanks.

Comment: You can. If your data is used only in your component you don't need to put it in the "global" redux state : http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state

Comment: If you found an answer useful, please do not forget to accept one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Below a list of rules of thumb which could help you to determinate what kind of data should be put into Redux or in your component, I tried to write down few assumptions, but please in mind you know only the right answers :):

- Is the data used by other part of your application? Probably in your case yes as a User Profile property like name could be used in different components, like the head of your site, profile details, basket.
- Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
- Is the same data being used by multiple components? Probably yes.
- Do you need to cache the data? Probably no.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful :)

Comment: And where to save the fetched data? Under the state, or under "this"

Comment: @user3712353 if you use redux to save your state, you should save in your store. The reducer will get an action when your ajax call is completed. The reducer will save the payload information in your store.

Comment: I mean if I fetch without redux - with the componentDidMound

Comment: @user3712353 please provide code sample of your react component so we can have a look to the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this is how you would fetch it if there wasn't redux being used.

If you want to use redux (to make profiles available in general etc.), you should call the action from `componentDidMount` to properly handle lifecycle events etc.